# about Fourier transformation on zero-padded vector

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis

I have a vector $x$ of n elements. I did a fft on it and return another vector of n elements also (i.e.$X = \text{fft}(x)$). Now I am trying to pad the $x$ vector by n zeros so to get $y$

$$
  y = [x \quad \underbrace{0 \quad 0\quad \cdots \quad 0 \quad 0}_{n}]^T
$$

I obtain fft on y also $Y = \text{fft}(y)$. I wonder if there is any mathematical relation between $X$ and $Y$. Instead of obtaining Y by fft on 2nx1 vectors, is that any way to obtain it from $X$? I have several trails with matlab, I see that all element at even index of Y is basically X but what about the other elements of Y, how do I get that directly from $X$?

Actually, what I am wondering if instead of performing fft of 2nx1 vector, is that possible to get it by 2 fft of 2 nx1 vector (one of them is fft(X)) ?

Answer (score 1):

What you get by zero-padding is some sort of convolution between $\operatorname{sinc} x:=\frac{\sin \pi x}{\pi x}$ and your signal. Here $\operatorname{sinc} x$ is the Fourier transform of the rectangular window, with which you implicitly multiplied your signal in Fourier space.

In this case, since $Y$ has twice as many points as $X$, you get $Y_{2i+1}=\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty X_j \operatorname{sinc} (i-j+\frac{1}{2})$, where $X_j$ is continued periodically for $j<0$ and $j\geq n$. This infinite sum can be converted into a finite sum with an appropriately modified convolution kernel instead of $\operatorname{sinc} x$, but I'm too lazy to work this out or look it up right now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am just starting, I don't understand most of the concept you mention here. I just wonder when you write $y_{2i+1} = \sum sinc(i-j+1/2)x_j$, what do you really mean? You mean the element of the double-length signal $y$ is multiplication of sinc function and the original x signal? Is this "multiplication" actually a convolution such that Y = FFT(sinc)*FFT(x). It is confusing to me since if this is the case, FFT(x) will gives vector of nx1 but the length of Y should be 2nx1.

Comment: @user1285419 I tried to make the notation less confusing now. The "multiplication" is a convolution, but FFT(sinc) is not well defined, because sinc is neither periodic nor has compact support. But maybe I should be less lazy and really work out the exact convolution kernel for the finite sum, maybe this would clarify things. For the exact convolution kernel, FFT(kernel) would actually be well defined, and mean more or less what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab e.g. we have
\begin{align}
X(k) &= \sum_{j=1}^N x(j) e^{-2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/N} \\
Y(k) &= \sum_{j=1}^{2N} y(j) e^{-2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/2N} =\sum_{j=1}^{N} x(j) e^{-2\pi i (j-1)(k-1)/2N}
\end{align}
so $Y(2k-1)=X(k)$ explaining every other point of $Y$.

Comment: Yes, but my question is what about the other points at 2k? Any way I write it in terms of X?